# natvis display of linked list that ends in raw view

Tags: visual-studio, natvis

I have this

```
struct llist {
  char code[CODE_SIZE];
...
  llist *next;
}
```

And my natvis file contains this

```
<Type Name="llist">
    <DisplayString>Code ={code,na}</DisplayString>
    <StringView>code</StringView>
    <Expand>
        <LinkedListItems>
            <HeadPointer>this</HeadPointer>
            <NextPointer>next</NextPointer>
            <ValueNode>this</ValueNode>
        </LinkedListItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>
```

I see

> pt_llist | 0x... Code ="Default"

This is good, and when I expand the var I see the linked list as a list of items.
When I expand one of the children I see a list from that point, what I want is the raw data now.
I changed this line `<ValueNode>this,!</ValueNode>`, this gives me the list but with raw data.
[image]

How do I get my list formatted the way I want and only when I expand a child will it display the raw data?

This might not be doable with the struct I have. But it is legacy code and I can't change it anytime soon. So I was just hoping to have a way to see the data better in debug.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugger cannot determine if you want a simple one element only view or the list view. But you can for example have a default view and a simple view. The default view can display all elements and the simple view can only display the element itself. Here is a small adjustment to your natvis that shows what I mean:

```
<Type Name="llist">
  <DisplayString>Code ={code,na}</DisplayString>
  <StringView>code</StringView>
  <Expand>
    <LinkedListItems ExcludeView="simple">
      <HeadPointer>this</HeadPointer>
      <NextPointer>next</NextPointer>
      <ValueNode>this,view(simple)</ValueNode>
    </LinkedListItems>
  </Expand>
</Type>
```

This displays as
[image: output in debugger]

The trick is to use the `ExcludeView="..."` and `,view(...)` as described on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2022#natvis-views). The name "simple" was my choice, you can choose any other name. You can even have multiple views.

Comment: Thank you, that helps greatly. How did you know to use the 'view' and 'simple'? Are they keywords or did you create the association by the definitions? I'm finding help on this lacking.

Comment: @MarkTwombley Good question. The `ExcludeView="..."` and `,view(...)` are described on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2022#natvis-views). The name "simple" was my choice. I added that information to my answer.